# Remove the "harminoca" tag and merge with harmonica

Tags: support, tags

https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harminoca

Comment: Removed tag on the one question, but don't have privileges to delete tag itself.

Comment: @Dave as long as the wiki and excerpt are gone, the tag will delete itself overnight.

Comment: @Dom - even if it has a wiki, with 0 questions it'll be deleted. If it has no wiki and *1* question it'll be deleted.

Comment: @Mithrandir that's not correct. Here's just one example of a tag with no wiki and 1 question:  (https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rudiments). There are other examples on the site.

Comment: @Dom - they don't get removed after a day, like the ones with no questions at all. It takes longer, several months.

Answer (score 3):

Tag has been  auto-deleted since I'd removed it from the one question that had it.

I did some web searches but I could not find any reference to "harminoca" as a musical term (e.g. a synonym for chromatic harmonica), so I'm pretty sure it was just a mis-spelling.